# JavaScript parameter between <%%>

Tags: .net, javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a 'demo' controller with 'demo' action that gets a parameter, and I want to give them in JavaScript.

aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openDefault(miez) {
       var manager1 = $find("<%= RadWindowManager2.ClientID %>");
       var str = "/demo/demo/" + miez;
       manager1.open(str3, "RadWindow2");
}  
</script>
```

It works if I give them one parameter, but for example miez="par1 par2", it doesn't works. (of course, because `/demo/demo/park1 par2` address doesn't exists).

So I tried another way:

aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openDefault(miez) {
       var manager1 = $find("<%= RadWindowManager2.ClientID %>");
       manager1.open('<% Url.Action("demo", "demo") %>', "RadWindow2");
}  
</script>
```

This works without parameters. The problem is that I don't know how can I give parameter using this form, if the parameter is a JavaScript variable.

```
manager1.open('<% Url.Action("demo", "demo",new{id="par1"}) %>', "RadWindow2");
```

How can I get 'par1' to replace the value of 'miez'?

Comment: ps:
I can't set miez value in ViewData before calling javascript

Comment: Hmm, your code is not really working, maybe some cut and paste errors? I.e., what's in `str3`?

Comment: ok, first of all, the ASP.NET code is used to *generate* the javascript source. it creates what you see when you right click and view source. the two can never interact in that direction. so nothing remotely like this will be possible, but perhaps there are other solutions. i'm failing to see exactly what your problem is tho. if `/demo/demo/par1 par2` doesn't exist, why would you ever pass that value to `openDefault` and what do you *want* to happen when you pass that value?

Comment: Can you edit your question so that it shows what actual output URL you expect and where/how those two parameters are supposed to end up?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the output of the `Url.Action("demo", "demo")` server side code, you should place it in a `<%=%>` section:

```
manager1.open('<%= Url.Action("demo", "demo",new{id="par1"}) %>', "RadWindow2");
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, try using `<%= %>` in stead of `<% %>`

The first will insert the output of the expression into the page, the second will only execute the code and do nothing with the output.

Second thing you need to realize that anything within `<% %>` is executed at the server. You cannot change what happens in there on the client.

What you probably want to do is generate the url using some sort of placeholder and then replacing the value in javascript.

Something like this:

```
var baseUrl = '<%= Url.Action("demo", "demo",new{id="par1"}) %>';
var url = baseUrl.replace('par1', 'miez');
```